# Error on Tkinter import

Tags: python, import, tkinter

I'm writing a Tkinter app in Python 2.7, but I'm running into some troubles that I haven't had before.  From what I can tell, it looks like the Tkinter module is getting imported for the `__init__` function in my class, but not for the other functions.  Here's a simplified version of what I've got:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk()
        self.window = Frame(self.master)
        self.window.grid()

        self.BuildFrames()
        self.master.mainloop()

    def BuildFrames(self):
        frames = []
        frames.append(Frame(self.window,borderwidth=2,padx=10,pady=10))
        # more code follows...

        for Frame in frames:
            Frame.grid()


App()
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myApp.py", line 131, in <module>
    App()
  File "myApp.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.BuildFrames()
  File "myApp.py", line 26, in BuildFrames
    frame1 = Frame(self.window,borderwidth=2,padx=10,pady=10)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Frame' referenced before assignment
```

From what I can tell, the `Frame` function isn't being recognized as a Tkinter method within the `BuildFrames()` function.  How on earth could it be recognized in `__init__` but not within `BuildFrames`???

I can fix the problem by changing the import to:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
```

and then adding a `Tk.` in front of all the Tkinter methods, but would rather avoid it (and I shouldn't have to do this anyway!)

I must be missing something big about the way the import works, but I could swear this same type of code has worked for me before.  Can someone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somewhere in your code, `Frame = ...` exists. Rename that variable to other than `Frame`.

You are doing something like following code:

```
>>> def f():
...     a + 1
...     a = 0
... 
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

[Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

**EDIT**

Change your BuildFrames as follow:

```
def BuildFrames(self):
    frames = []
    frames.append(Frame(self.window,borderwidth=2,padx=10,pady=10))
    # more code follows...

    for frame in frames:
        frame.grid()
```

Comment: I'm quite positive that I don't have any other definitions of `Frame` in my code.  Is there anything that could cause the import to not be recognized within all modules of a class?

Comment: found the error... turns out I used a variable `Frame` within an iterator later down in `BuildFrames`.  I'll post the code as an answer.

Comment: @user1636547, Do not post that as answer! Update your original post.

Comment: Done.  From the updated post, the error lies when I try to iterate over my `frames` list

Comment: @user1636547, I updated the answer.  `for frame in frames:` has similar effect of `frame = frames[..]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to `Frame` somewhere in that function

```
    frame1 = Frame(self.window,borderwidth=2,padx=10,pady=10)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Frame' referenced before assignment
```

Since you are assigning to it, Python knows it must be a local variable, so isn't looking at the global one.

Here is a simple example of this problem

```
a = 1
def f():
    b = a + 1
    a = b + 1  # If this wasn't here, the above line would use the global `a`
f()
```

If it's still not clear, include the code that follows (the rest of the function), and we'll point it out for you

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that you're doing a global import. Thus, the frame widget is imported as `Frame`.

When you do `for Frame in frames`, you are *overwriting* the Frame class with a local variable named `Frame` since you can't have two things with the same name.

Because of the way python was designed, it recognizes that you're creating a local variable named "Frame" before any code in that function runs. So, when you do this code:

```
frames.append(Frame(self.window,borderwidth=2,padx=10,pady=10))
```

... the `Frame` class no longer exists, as it has been replaced by the local variable. And since you haven't yet assigned a value to the local variable "Frame", you get the error that you do.

The fix is pretty simple: don't create a local variable named "Frame", and/or don't do global imports.